# How to convert string to Title Case in Python?

Tags: python

Example:

```
HILO -> Hilo
new york -> New York
SAN FRANCISCO -> San Francisco
```

Is there a library or standard way to perform this task?

Comment: That isn't "CamelCase", that's "Capitalize"; which do you want?

Comment: camelCase isLike this.

Comment: Your examples use PascalCase.

Comment: I used this one and it worked pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74912560/17598016

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Why not use [`title`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) Right from the docs:

```
>>> "they're bill's friends from the UK".title()
"They'Re Bill'S Friends From The Uk"
```

If you really wanted PascalCase you can use this:

```
>>> ''.join(x for x in 'make IT pascal CaSe'.title() if not x.isspace())
'MakeItPascalCase'
```

Comment: I think the 'r' in "They're" ought to be lower case. And the 's' in "Bill's" definitely must be lower case.

Comment: @Daniel - That issue is noted in the docs for `title`: "The algorithm uses a simple language-independent definition of a word as groups of consecutive letters. The definition works in many contexts but it means that apostrophes in contractions and possessives form word boundaries, which may not be the desired result".  One possible solution would be to use Laurence's answer with the regex `r"['\w]+"` so apostrophes wouldn't end a match (additional punctuation could be added as needed).

Comment: For the record, a neater way to do the last CamelCase example is as `'make IT camel CaSe'.title().replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: If anyone else feels like they're on crazy pills -- this is PascalCase, not camelCase.

Comment: Nice code but camelCase doesn't start with a CAPITAL.  Try this:

`def toCamel(s):
    ret = ''.join(x for x in s.title() if not x.isspace())
    return ret[0].lower() + ret[1:]
`

Usage:
`toCamel("WRITE this in camelcase")
'writeThisInCamelcase'
`

Comment: I just met `title()`. Deep.

Answer (score 34):

This one would always start with lowercase, and also strip non alphanumeric characters:

```
def camelCase(st):
    output = ''.join(x for x in st.title() if x.isalnum())
    return output[0].lower() + output[1:]
```

Answer (score 15):

```
def capitalizeWords(s):
  return re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m:m.group(0).capitalize(), s)
```

`re.sub` can take a function for the "replacement" (rather than just a string, which is the usage most people seem to be familiar with). This repl function will be called with an `re.Match` object for each match of the pattern, and the result (which should be a string) will be used as a replacement for that match.

A longer version of the same thing:

```
WORD_RE = re.compile(r'\w+')

def capitalizeMatch(m):
  return m.group(0).capitalize()

def capitalizeWords(s):
  return WORD_RE.sub(capitalizeMatch, s)
```

This pre-compiles the pattern (generally considered good form) and uses a named function instead of a lambda.

Comment: this one is pretty neat, I am trying to get my head around lambda functions, thank you for helping

Comment: @JohnMachin I just asked because I thought adding some explanation would make your answer more complete and better.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves what is lambda doing here?

Comment: what is lambda doing here? from wha I can decipher and from you explaination. this is what I understood. when you use a function in re.sub each `match` will be passed to the function? and since `matches` in regular expressions have groups. thats why this line exists `lambda m:m.group(0).capitalize()`?

Comment: @Zion yes. When `re.sub` is given a callable (eg: a function) as the "replacement", it passes the match object to that callable, and expects to get back a string which is what it actually uses as the replacement. If you find lambdas confusing, the "longer version" does exactly the same thing in a more verbose way.

Answer (score 8):

Potential library: https://pypi.org/project/stringcase/

Example:

```
import stringcase
stringcase.camelcase('foo_bar_baz') # => "fooBarBaz"
```

Though it's questionable whether it will leave spaces in.  (Examples show it removing space, but there is a bug tracker issue noting that it leaves them in.)

Comment: Heck yes. Was looking for a package. This package has snakecase and other conversion functions as well.

Answer (score 7):

just use .title(), and it will convert first letter of every word in capital, rest in small:

```
>>> a='mohs shahid ss'
>>> a.title()
'Mohs Shahid Ss'
>>> a='TRUE'
>>> b=a.title()
>>> b
'True'
>>> eval(b)
True
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not write one? Something like this may satisfy your requirements:

```
def FixCase(st):
    return ' '.join(''.join([w[0].upper(), w[1:].lower()]) for w in st.split())
```

Comment: thanks, that helped completely. My bad, I didn't think to write one in first place

Answer (score 6):

**Note: Why am I providing yet another answer?** *This answer is based on the title of the question and the notion that camelcase is defined as: a series of words that have been concatenated (no spaces!) such that each of the original words start with a capital letter (the rest being lowercase) excepting the first word of the series (which is completely lowercase). Also it is assumed that "all strings" refers to ASCII character set; unicode would not work with this solution).*

### simple

Given the above definition, this function

```
import re
word_regex_pattern = re.compile("[^A-Za-z]+")

def camel(chars):
  words = word_regex_pattern.split(chars)
  return "".join(w.lower() if i is 0 else w.title() for i, w in enumerate(words))
```

, when called, would result in this manner

```
camel("San Francisco")  # sanFrancisco
camel("SAN-FRANCISCO")  # sanFrancisco
camel("san_francisco")  # sanFrancisco
```

### less simple

Note that it fails when presented with an already camel cased string!

```
camel("sanFrancisco")   # sanfrancisco  <-- noted limitation
```

### even less simple

Note that it fails with many unicode strings

```
camel("México City")    # mXicoCity     <-- can't handle unicode
```

I don't have a solution for these cases(or other ones that could be introduced with some creativity). So, as in all things that have to do with strings, cover your own edge cases and good luck with unicode!

Comment: How can you determine that a string is Camel case without knowing the meaning of the sentence? In your "less simple" example, "sanfRancisco" is Camel case as well as "itSnotcaMelcAse".

Comment: I'm guessing your input had apostraphes or other punctuation? I should note other failed input. Definitely a good catch. What was the input you provided?

Comment: I mean than a sequence of characters without space must be consider as 1 word. You can not extract work from it without knowing the meaning of the sentence. Put "sanfRancisco" or "itSnotcaMelcAse" as input of camello() and you will see that the output will be the same.

Comment: Oh I see - yeah, I think you're right.  I overfit the solution.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def camelCase(st):
    s = st.title()
    d = "".join(s.split())
    d = d.replace(d[0],d[0].lower())
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my little contribution to this post:

```
def to_camelcase(str):
  return ' '.join([t.title() for t in str.split()])
```

Comment: Actually, str.title() is the same and you are saving up computational cost.

Answer (score 0):

From code wars - Write simple .camelCase method in Python for strings. All words must have their first letter capitalized without spaces.
camelcase("hello case") => HelloCase
camelcase("camel case word") => CamelCaseWord

```
def camel_case(string):
    titled_string = string.title()
    space_joined_string = titled_string.replace(' ', '')
    return space_joined_string
```