# Python: convert variable-like strings to class-like strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm having trouble trying to create a function that can do this job. The objective is to convert strings like

- `one` to `One`
- `hello_world` to `HelloWorld`
- `foo_bar_baz` to `FooBarBaz`

I know that the proper way to do this is using `re.sub`, but I'm having trouble creating the right regular expressions to do the job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347048/camelcase-every-string-any-standard-library

Comment: Thanks, this seems good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> s = 'one'
>>> filter(str.isalnum, s.title())
'One'
>>>
>>> s = 'hello_world'
>>> filter(str.isalnum, s.title())
'HelloWorld'
>>> 
>>> s = 'foo_bar_baz'
>>> filter(str.isalnum, s.title())
'FooBarBaz'
```

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [`str.title()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)
- [`str.isalnum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)
- [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: The first solution is beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
def uppercase(name):
    return ''.join(x for x in name.title() if not x.isspace()).replace('_', '')
```