# Jaden Casing String: How to return a sentence string with capitalised words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to create a function that takes a short text and returns it in the so-called *Jaden Case* mode where each word's first letter is a capital ([best reference I could find](https://repl.it/@kafil_kiron/Jaden-Casing-StringsTitle-Case-A-Sentence-CodeWars)).

For example `"Hi, I'm twenty years old"` should return `"Hi I'm Twenty Years Old"`.

I have tried to solve this problem on my own, but the letter after the apostrophe sign becomes a capital whereas it shouldn't..

My attempt:

```
def toJadenCase(string):
    for letter in string:
        if letter == "\'" :
            letter[+1].lowercase()
        else:
            return string.title()
    return string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to Title Case in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347048/how-to-convert-string-to-title-case-in-python)

Answer (score 11):

Use `str.split` and `str.capitalize`:

```
s = "Hi, I'm twenty years old"
' '.join([i.capitalize() for i in s.split()])
```

Output:

```
"Hi, I'm Twenty Years Old"
```

Comment: nitpick: `join` [is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function) when provided with a list rather than a genexp.

Comment: Wow, never knew that. Thanks for the info :) I've editted

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in another two methods:

Method#1

```
import string

def tojaden(jadencase):
    return string.capwords(jadencase)

print(tojaden("I'm iron man"))
```

Method#2

```
def jadencase(str):
    s1 = str.split()
    capWords = []
    for word in s1:
        caps = word.capitalize()
        capWords.append(caps)
    final_string = " ".join(capWords)
    print(final_string)


jadencase("it ain't me")
```