# how to extract Values from list of tuples python

Tags: python, python-3.x

my input is

```
[('XXXXX', 'testing something ', 'testing somethng2', testing something3)]
```

expected output is

```
XXXX
Testing Something
testing somethng2
testing something3
```

Comment: It is import for the community to demonstrate that you are **also* working to solve your issue. Please include the **text** based code that you have already tried highlighting where you are struggling.

Comment: `testing something3` is invalid syntax. It's supposed to be a string, right? Please [edit] to fix.

Comment: Why is `Testing Something` capitalized in the output? If you need to learn how to do that, see [How to convert string to Title Case in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8347048/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list has a single item which is a tuple, just grab that using `[0]` then :

```
inp = [('XXXXX', 'testing something ', 'testing somethng2', 'testing something3')]
print(' '.join(inp[0]))
```

output :
`XXXXX testing something  testing somethng2 testing something3`

Another solution would be:

```
print(*inp[0], sep=' ')
```

Output : `XXXXX testing something  testing somethng2 testing something3`

Comment: Thank you Sorous, it worked.. if my input has a none value example [('testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', None)] if the 4 value is None, i am getting error expected Str, nontype found

Comment: for covering the scenario which has none
inp = [('XXXXX', 'testing something ', 'testing somethng2', None)]
print(' || '.join(str(item) for item in inp[0]))

Comment: @maheshnair I've edited my answer, with solution number 2 you can have None or integers and etc in that tuple.